# Is there a better way to create a list of values of a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I made a nested dictionary

```
d = {
    'first':{
        'key': 'A',
        'val': 1
    },
    'second':{
        'key': 'A',
        'val': 2
    },
    'third':{
        'key': 'B',
        'val': 5
    },
    'fourth':{
        'key': 'B',
        'val': 7
    }
}
```

Now suppose I wanted to create a list of values of the nested dictionaries with key being 'key'.
What I mean by that is, I want a list of such manner:

```
L = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
```

I managed to do it with the help of for loops and value() in this manner:

```
List = d.values()
L = []
for K in List:
    L.append(K['key'])
print(L)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
```

but is there something cleaner out there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a list of an inner value from a dict of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266642/create-a-list-of-an-inner-value-from-a-dict-of-dicts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write like :

```
keys_list = [record['key'] for record in d.values()]
```

it will get the values that you mentioned in the output.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a list comprehension

```
print([v['key'] for v in d.values()])
```

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension to the rescue

```
[d[x]['key'] for x in d]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using map function like:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x['key'], d.values())))
```